# Type object as type argument for generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Type `bar` is specified as an instance of `Type` class and passed to method `Foo(Type bar)`. 
A generic method `Foo<bar>` is in another assembly that needs the type argument `bar`.

**How can I pass `bar` as a type argument for `Foo<bar>`?**

It should look something like this:

> ```
>     object Foo(Type bar)
>     {
>         return AnotherAssembly.Foo<barAsTypeArgument>();
>     }
> ```

Comment: You can pass type `Type` of `bar` to generic method, like `Foo<Type>()`

Comment: the most easiest is to update yours `Foo` method to be generic too and to pass generic argument to the `AnotherAssembly.Foo<>`